# Пересечение данных в разных потоках

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть параллельное выполнение с помощью функции `AsParallel()` некоторого цикла. В данном цикле создается один и тот же объект с разными входными данными в каждом потоке. Так вот, все потоки параллельно обрабатывают данные своего объекта, но, получается так, что один поток изменяет данные объекта другого потока. Как можно сделать так, что разные потоки изменяли данные объекта именно в своем потоке и не лезли в чужой?

Полностью все классы описывать не стану, вот код именно расчетов :

```
        lock(locker)
{
        if (GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.GetItem(Security.nameSecurity + Security.Timeframe + Security.start + Security.end + F + "SMA") != null)
        {
            Fast = GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.GetItem(Security.nameSecurity + Security.Timeframe + Security.start + Security.end + F + "SMA");
        }
        else
        {
            Fast = iMa.MA.SMA(sec.ClosePrice, F);
            GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.AddItem(Security.nameSecurity + Security.Timeframe + Security.start + Security.end + F + "SMA", Fast);
        }



        if (GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.GetItem(Security.nameSecurity + Security.Timeframe + Security.start + Security.end + S + "SMA") != null)
        {
            Slow = GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.GetItem(Security.nameSecurity + Security.Timeframe + Security.start + Security.end + S + "SMA");
        }
        else
        {

            Slow = iMa.MA.SMA(sec.ClosePrice, S);
            GlobalCachingProvider.Instance.AddItem(Security.nameSecurity + Security.Timeframe + Security.start + Security.end + S + "SMA", Slow);
        }
}


        int count = sec.ClosePrice.Count;
        int i;
        for (i = 2; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            sec.Positions.barProfit.Add(sec.Positions.allProfit());
            Position pos = sec.Positions.getLastPosition();
            if (pos == null)
            {
                if (Fast[i - 1] < Slow[i - 1] && Fast[i] > Slow[i])
                {
                    sec.Positions.BuyAtMarket(sec.OpenPrice[i + 1], i + 1, 1, "LE");
                    break;
                }
                else if (Fast[i - 1] > Slow[i - 1] && Fast[i] < Slow[i])
                {
                    sec.Positions.SellAtMarket(sec.OpenPrice[i + 1], i + 1, 1, "SE");
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
        for (i++; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            Position pos = sec.Positions.getLastPosition();
            if (Fast[i - 1] < Slow[i - 1] && Fast[i] > Slow[i])
            {
                pos.CloseAtMarket(sec.OpenPrice[i + 1], "CSE");
                sec.Positions.BuyAtMarket(sec.OpenPrice[i + 1], i + 1, 1, "LE");
            }
            else if (Fast[i - 1] > Slow[i - 1] && Fast[i] < Slow[i])
            {
                pos.CloseAtMarket(sec.OpenPrice[i + 1], "CLE");
                sec.Positions.SellAtMarket(sec.OpenPrice[i + 1], i + 1, 1, "SE");
            }
            sec.Positions.barProfit.Add(sec.Positions.allProfit());
        }

        Position posit = sec.Positions.getLastPosition();
        if (posit != null)
        {
            posit.CloseAtMarket(sec.ClosePrice[count - 1], "OpenPos");
        }
        if (sec.Positions.allCountPosition() < 100)
        {
            if (z == 0)
            {
                Form1.time.Add(Form1.gg.Elapsed);
                z = 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            double res = Math.Round(sec.Positions.getCAGR() / Math.Abs(sec.Positions.getMaxDrawdown()), 2);
            if (res > 0)
            {
                if (z == 0)
                {
                    Form1.time.Add(Form1.gg.Elapsed);
                    z = 1;
                }
                param.Add(Tuple.Create(F,S));
                return res;

            }
            else
            {
                if (z == 0)
                {
                    Form1.time.Add(Form1.gg.Elapsed);
                    z = 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Получается, у меня есть основной класс Security. В нем создается объект PositionList и там уже создается список Positions. Здесь я пока не ставил эту функцию в многопоточность, но грубо говоря, без многопоточности результаты верные, а так, почему-то тот же самый проход с одними и теми же параметрами дает другие результаты)

Функция многопоточности выглядит так

```
public double resultOpt()
{
var max = GetItems().AsParallel().Max(t=>OptimCalc(t.item1,t.Item2));
return max;
}

IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> GetItems()
{
  for(int i=5;i<50;i=i+5)
  {
    for(int j = i + 5; j < 50; j = j + 5)
    {
       yield return Tuple.Create(i,j);
    }
  }
}
```

Функцию OptimCalc я привел выше. Самые основные изменения в функции идут в списке `List<Positions>`. В функциях BuyAtMarket, ClosePosition, я лишь добавляю в список вначале элемент с данными. А при закрытии я изменяю у данного элемента некоторые поля. Вот и всё.

Comment: Синхронизация потоков https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.4.php

Comment: Так не бывает, если не постараться специально. Если объект создаётся локально, то он и доступен только локально. У вас есть какие-то общие, разделяемые между объектами данные? (Может быть, вы по ошибке используете статические поля?) Покажите ваш код, без него мы можем только гадать, где именно ошибка.